# How to call confirm dialog from server side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a button in my page, the click event of which executes certain code if a condition is matched else it asks for confirmation whether to continue. I have a javascript function for confirm as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function getConfirmation(){
               var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
               if( retVal == true ){

                  return true;
               }
               else{

                  return false;
               }
            }

      </script>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="lnkBtn" onClick="lnkBtn_Click" onClientClick="getConfirmation()"></button>
```

The code behind looks like this:

```
   void lnkBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtMyText.Text!="")
        {
        ///need confirmation here whether to continue.  
        }
        else
        {
        //continue with normal code.    
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is the confirm() is fired when the button is clicked even when the condition is not met. I want the confirm() to fire only when the condition is met. Please help me do this.

Thanking you in anticipation.

I tried both the solutions but it seems I am making a mistake somewhere. I am attaching the full code below. Request you to kindly help me find out where I am wrong and how I can fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Confirm() {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            if (confirm("This will completely delete the project. Are you sure?")) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            }
            else {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
    </script>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="lnkBtn" onClick="lnkBtn_Click" onClientClick="getConfirmation()"></button>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void ibExport_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            string str=gdView.HeaderRow.Cells[8].Text;
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtID = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)gdView.Rows[0].Cells[8].FindControl(str);
            if (txtID.Text != "")
            {
                string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
                if (confirmValue == "Yes")
                {
                    MyAlert("Yes clicked");
                }
                else
                {
                    MyAlert("No clicked");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MyAlert("No Text found.");
            }
        }
```

When ibExport is clicked with txtID.Text !=" ", no confirm dialog box is displayed. Instead the "No clicked" alert pops up directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, use `return` statement in the inline click handler.

```
onClientClick="return getConfirmation()"
```

instead of

```
onClientClick="getConfirmation()"
```

Additionally, `if` block in the `getConfirmation` function is redundant

```
function getConfirmation() {
    return confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove Your Javascript. and instead use this function in Backend for button click event.

```
void lnkBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtMyText.Text!="")
        {
             Response.Write("<script> function getConfirmation()"
            +" { var retVal = confirm('Do you want to continue ?');"
            +" if( retVal == true )"
            +" { return true; } else{ return false;} }"
            +" </script>");
        }
        else
        {
        //continue with normal code.    
        }
    }
```